# Show HTML text without executing it

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a tooltip:

```
         <i
            class="fa fa-info-circle infopoint"
            role="button"
            data-toggle="popover"
            data-placement="top"
            data-trigger="hover"
            data-content="<a href='qwe'>URL text</a>."
        ></i>
```

And I need to show exactly like this, without transforming it in a link. I'm writing it in Blade template. And I've tried `{!! !!}` and `{{ }}` and `html_entity_decode`.

Comment: Change the four  < to &lt;

Comment: `html_entity_decode()` _decodes_ html entities to actual html again so that's definitely not what you want. You want to _encode_ the string to html entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) should do the trick

```
htmlspecialchars('<i
        class="fa fa-info-circle infopoint"
        role="button"
        data-toggle="popover"
        data-placement="top"
        data-trigger="hover"
        data-content="<a href="qwe">URL text</a>."
    ></i>');
```

If you only want `data-content` to show as text

```
data-content=" {{ htmlspecialchars("<a href='qwe'>Your html code</a>") }}"
```

Comment: If I would guess, then it's only the `data-content`-string that should be encoded (since the OP mentions: _"without transforming it in a link"_).

Comment: `data-content=" {{ htmlspecialchars("<a href='qwe'>Your html code</a>") }}"`
It works. Thank you.
Please fix your answer so I can mark it as correct one.

Comment: @NikitaYunoshev added `data-content` solution to the answer